# Azure Data Factory Publish branch option vs publish_config.json

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I see a new feature in ADF which is a listbox to select the branch to do the publish. So the mandatory adf_publish is not needed anymore.

But we also had a publish_config.json option to redirect to the branch we like. If we use both i.e UI points to branchA and publish_config.json points to branchB, which branch will be used?

Answer (score 0):

I think the UI just displays what is in the file.

Comment: Hi @BlueClouds, do you mind sharing your test result here? It should be the best answer

Comment: My test was simple. UI never worked. Wondering if anyone got UI working